# Android GCM: registering and receiving the Android application's messages from other app

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm reading the android docs for Android GCM at https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

Then i noticed the part below:

> Your  + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE" permission
>   to prevent other Android applications from registering and receiving
>   the Android application's messages. The permission name must exactly
>   match this pattern—otherwise the Android application will not receive
>   the messages.

The example code:

```
<permission android:name="<your-package-name>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="<your-package-name>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

The above code, it seem declare a custom permision then use it. Right?

Now i have two questions about this:

- First, as the document mentioned "to prevent other Android applications from registering and receiving the Android application's messages", so it means we can register and receive message from other applicaiton some how. Can we? how can we do it?
- Last, i'm not really understand how it work? I mean the example code above.

Could you help!?
(Ah, i see a quite same question here [How does android permission.C2D_MESSAGE work to prevent other people mimic my client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26456234/how-does-android-permission-c2d-message-work-to-prevent-other-people-mimic-my-cl) - but it is 1 year old question and nothing update till now, so hope that we have some update)

Comment: This will help you. http://javapapers.com/android/android-device-to-device-messaging-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-via-http/

Answer (score 1):

This answer is an educated guess.  I think an authoritative answer could only come from a Google insider with access to the code.

An important aspect of the `com.your.pkg.permission.C2D_MESSAGE`that a GCM client app must declare is that its protection level is Signature. [The documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html) explains that a signature level permission is:

> A permission that the system grants only if the requesting application
>   is signed with the same certificate as the application that declared
>   the permission.

This means that the system will never grant the C2D_MESSAGE permission you declare to any app that is not signed by you.

When the GCM framework receives a downstream message it knows the package name of the application the message should be delivered to.  I don't know how the framework obtains that information. Perhaps it is included in the metadata for the message.  When you create the credentials for your GCM client app at the Google Developers Console, you provide the package name. The result is an association of (API Key, Sender ID, Package Name, and SHA-1 Fingerprint).  It's plausible that the GCM server uses that data to include the target package name in the message metadata.

Using the package name, the GCM framework can create the full C2D_MESSAGE permission string and use the [Context.sendBroadcast()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.String)) method that includes the permission.  The broadcast will then only be delivered to instances of [GcmReceiver](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmReceiver) that hold that permission, which in this case is the one in your app and only that one.